# Deleting from mysql database using timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query like this :

```
DELETE FROM DOCUMENTAUDIT D WHERE D.AUDITSYSDATE LIKE '11/07/2023%';
```

AUDITSYSDATE is of type DATE which captures the system date,i.e, time stamps of when the data was inserted in the data base. But when I am executing query no rows are being deleted. The format is the same I checked.

My above query is to delete all the rows which I inserted today.

Comment: How you have the date in the table? As `DD/MM/YYY` or `YY-MM-DD` format?  MySQL has default format as `YYYY-MM-DD`. And you may try `LIKE '2023-07-11%'`

Comment: "Using timestamp" from the title sounds strange, as you are not using any timestamp in your query

Comment: It's the DD/MM/YYYY format because when I retrieve using select * query, it's being shown something like this :   11/07/2023 13:37:12

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the table structure. When I query a table with a DATE column, it shows the data in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, like `2023-07-11` for the current day. Usually, a date column won't store the time either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try comparing just the Date part of AUDITSYSDATE and it should work for you:

```
DELETE FROM DOCUMENTAUDIT D WHERE DATE(D.AUDITSYSDATE) = '11-07-2023';
```

Make sure you put the date in the right format in the above query.